# How to Change Piecemaker Text on Controls?

Tags: html, text, controls

In Piecemaker, we have controls "play", "stop", "info" and "link" which appear on rollover.

**How can I change these texts?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After great efforts I found that these words are in "piecemaker.swf" file. I decompiled the swf and changed these images. But it didn't work.

As far as I see, we cannot change the images (even just colors) :(

If anyone finds a solution, please let me now.

Goodday!